# Token Error in Makefile for D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, makefile

I'm following [this tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/) to create a bubble map in d3js. I have the following in my Makefile:

```
build/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip:
mkdir -p $(dir $@)
curl -o $@ http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/$(notdir $@)

build/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp: build/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip
   unzip -od $(dir $@) $<
   touch $@

build/counties.json: build/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
   node_modules/.bin/topojson \
       -o $@ \
       --projection='width = 960, height = 600, d3.geo.albersUsa() \
        .scale(1280) \
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])' \
       --simplify=.5 \
       -- counties=$<
```

When I go to run the command to convert the shape file to json I get this error:

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL]
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'build/counties.json' failed
make: *** [build/counties.json] Error 1
```

I'm not sure what illegal token it could be or if I am missing something completely ... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not a problem in your makefile: make is invoking the `node_modules/.bin/topojson` command and that command is printing this error, not make.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this tutorial, and the solution to the above error actually does need a change to the makefile.

As explained in the [d3 Wiki on Github](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2149), the error results from the backslash-newlines being interpreted literally. The fix is to move the options for projection to the same line. Thus, it would go from this:

```
 --projection='width = 960, height = 600, d3.geo.albersUsa() \
    .scale(1280) \
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])' \
```

to this:

```
--projection='width = 960, height = 600, d3.geo.albersUsa() .scale(1280) .translate([width / 2, height / 2])' \
```